# Scrapy changing the animated gif to static gif after downloading

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to download the images from site using image pipeline.

The images are downloaded but animated gif have become static gif . those images are not animated any more.

how can I retain the animated gif after downloading

This is my pipeline

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    #Name download version
    def image_key(self, url):
        image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
        return 'full/%s' % (image_guid)

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
            if item['image_urls']:
            for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)
```

Comment: Can you provide some more source code? Also a link to the `ImagesPipeline` class? I assume it's part of `scrapy` but couldn't find the `ImagesPipeline` class in the source when quickly scanning code on github.

Comment: Are you 100% sure they are not animated? How have you determined that?

Comment: I tried opening them in IE and they are still , then i tried going to the url of image and it was animated. i only made the crawler for downloading animated GIF only but that didn't work. Does it has anything to do with PIL. may be PIL not support animated GIF but i am not sure

Comment: @Bartek - here you go: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py